# Extracting an ID (numeric) from a field in Teradata where the position varies

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm doing a tricky join using an ID from a description column where the position of the ID varies.

The issue is there are 2 8-digit IDs, and the code is pulling the 1st, or the CASE=. I need it to pull the ACT=. How do I do this?

```
CASE WHEN REQUEST_DSC LIKE '%ACT=%' 
     THEN RegExp_Substr(REQUEST_DSC, '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')
END
```

The description field is manually entered, and often (but not always, hence not using a position identifier) formatted like this:

```
CASE=00000000,ACT=00000000.
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround is to extract the `ACT=` and use `SUBSTR()`:

```
CASE WHEN REQUEST_DSC LIKE '%ACT=%' 
     THEN SUBSTR(RegExp_Substr(REQUEST_DSC, 'ACT=[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'), 5)
END
```

Comment: Thank you that worked! I'm new(er) to SQL and my mentor was advising me to use just substr to pull them. With the varied positions, though, we had quite a list of substr statements and it still wasn't picking up all of them.

Answer (score 0):

The data looks like a list of name/value pairs.

There's builtin funtion to extract values from such a list:

```
Nvp(REQUEST_DSC, 'ACT', ',', '=')
```

But this will only work if the delimiters are always the same, i.e `','` and `'='`, and it's case sensitive, i.e. `'act=00000000'` will not be found

Otherwise you can simplify Gordon's RegEx. Look for `'ACT='` without adding it (`'\K'`) to the overall match and then return the following digits (`'\d'`). The `i` requests a case insensitive match:

```
RegExp_Substr(REQUEST_DSC, 'ACT=\K\d{8}',   1, 1, 'i') -- exactly 8 digits
RegExp_Substr(REQUEST_DSC, 'ACT=\K\d{1,8}', 1, 1, 'i') -- 1 to 8 digits
RegExp_Substr(REQUEST_DSC, 'ACT=\K\d+',     1, 1, 'i') -- any number of digitd
```